# Counting and displaying sum of occurrences

Tags: matlab, count

Part of my data (cell array of strings) is shown below. I want to count the occurrences of particular strings (e.g., `'P0702'`, `'P0882'`, etc.) and display the sum of the occurrences in the form of the output shown below:

```
'1FA'   '2012'  'F' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' 'P0882' 
'1Fc'   '2012'  'r' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  
'1FA'   '2012'  'f' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' 'P0882' ''  
'1FA'   '2012'  'y' ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  
'1FA'   '2012'  'g' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  
'1FA'   '2012'  'u' ''  'P0702' 'P0882' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  
'1FA'   '2012'  'y' ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  
'1FA'   '2012'  'n' ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  
'1FA'   '2012'  'j' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702'                                
'1FA'   '2012'  'u' 'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  
'1FM'   '2013'  'x' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P1921' ''  ''  ''
'1FM'   '2013'  'c' ''  'P1711' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''
'1FM'   '2013'  'c' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' 'P0882' ''
'1FM'   '2009'  'E' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0500'
```

Output:

```
        sum of counts above      
P0702   15
P0500    1
P1711    1
```

and so on.

I tried using `sum(strcmp(d,{'P0882'}),2);` which tells me how many times `'P0882'` occurs, but it would be difficult to use it for every data string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do as follows, basically apply `strcmp` as you proposed but in a loop in which you pre-determined the unique strings/data names to count.

I modified a bit the data you provided so that dimensions fit. The code is commented and pretty easy to follow:

```
C = {'1FA'   '2012'  'F' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' 'P0882' ;
'1Fc'   '2012'  'r' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' '';
'1FA'   '2012'  'f' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' 'P0882';
'1FA'   '2012'  'y' ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ''  ''  '';
'1FA'   '2012'  'g' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  '';
'1FA'   '2012'  'u' ''  'P0702' 'P0882' ''  ''  ''  ''  ;
'1FA'   '2012'  'y' ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  '' ;
'1FA'   '2012'  'n' ''  'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  '' ;
'1FA'   '2012'  'j' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' ;  
'1FA'   '2012'  'u' 'P0702' ''  ''  ''  ''  '' '' ;
'1FM'   '2013'  'x' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P1921' '';
'1FM'   '2013'  'c' ''  'P1711' ''  ''  ''  ''  '';
'1FM'   '2013'  'c' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  'P0702' 'P0882';
'1FM'   '2009'  'E' ''  ''  ''  ''  ''  '' 'P0500'}

%// Find unique strings to count occurence of.
[strings,~,~] = unique(C(:,4:end));

%// Remove empty cells automatically.
strings = strings(~cellfun(@isempty,strings));

%// Initialize output cell array
Output = cell(numel(strings),2);

%// Count occurence. You can combine the 2 lines into one using concatenation.
for k = 1:numel(strings)

    Output{k,1} = strings{k};    
    Output{k,2} = sum(sum(strcmp(C(:,4:end),strings{k})));

end
```

Let's make a nice table out of this:

```
T = table(Output(:,2),'RowNames',Output(:,1),'VariableNames',{'TotalOccurences'})
```

Output:

```
T = 

             TotalOccurences
             _______________

    P0500    [ 1]           
    P0702    [10]           
    P0882    [ 4]           
    P1711    [ 1]           
    P1921    [ 1]
```

If you don't have access to the `table` function, you can create a cell array with headers and change a bit the loop:

```
%// Initialize output cell array
Output = cell(numel(strings)+1,2);

%// Count occurence
for k = 1:numel(strings)

    Output{k+1,1} = strings{k};    
    Output{k+1,2} = sum(sum(strcmp(C(:,4:end),strings{k})));

end
%T = table(Output(:,2),'RowNames',Output(:,1),'VariableNames',{'TotalOccurences'})

Output(1,:) = {'Data' 'Occurence'}
```

Output:

```
Output = 

    'Data'     'Occurence'
    'P0500'    [        1]
    'P0702'    [       10]
    'P0882'    [        4]
    'P1711'    [        1]
    'P1921'    [        1]
```

Comment: @Benoit_11-This works perfect except the last table part.I am using 2011b Version,so the table function throws up an error : Undefined function 'table' for input arguments of type 'cell'..Otherwise it works great.Thanks for time and help

Comment: Yes the `table` function was not in that release I believe. That does not matter you can use the `Output` cell array instead :) I will edit the answer

Comment: @Benoit_11- That's exactly what i did.Thanks again :)

Comment: great! Glad to help :)

Comment: @Benoit_11-I was wondering why sum(sum( has been used instead of sum(..i tried sum( and it throws an error,"number of columns in both inputs must be same".

Answer (score 2):

If you have the **Statistics Toolbox** you can simply use [**`tabulate`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html)

```
%// get only relevant part
X = data(:,4:end);

%// tabulate
tabulate(X(:))
```

---

It already gives a nicely formatted output:

```
  Value    Count   Percent
  P0702       10     58.82%
  P1711        1      5.88%
  P0882        4     23.53%
  P1921        1      5.88%
  P0500        1      5.88%
```

Alternatively with standard functions:

```
X = data(:,4:end)
[a,~,x] = unique(X(~strcmp(X,'')))
occ = hist(x(:),1:numel(a))
out = [a num2cell(occ).']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count ocurrences of all strings without loops. Let `C` be your cell array.

```
[uniqueStrings, ~, v] = unique(C);
counts = histc(v, 1:max(v));
result = [uniqueStrings(:) num2cell(counts(:))];
```

In your example, this gives

```
result = 
    ''         [81]
    '1FA'      [ 9]
    '1FM'      [ 4]
    '1Fc'      [ 1]
    '2009'     [ 1]
    '2012'     [10]
    '2013'     [ 3]
    'E'        [ 1]
    'F'        [ 1]
    'P0500'    [ 1]
    'P0702'    [10]
    'P0882'    [ 4]
    'P1711'    [ 1]
    'P1921'    [ 1]
    'c'        [ 2]
    'f'        [ 1]
    'g'        [ 1]
    'j'        [ 1]
    'n'        [ 1]
    'r'        [ 1]
    'u'        [ 2]
    'x'        [ 1]
    'y'        [ 2]
```

Comment: @all- appreciate your help !